# Qt just draw the first frame using QGLWidget from QT

Tags: qt, opengl, qglwidget

I coded a small QT program using QGLWidget. The goal is to display a simple triangle in permanent rotation. The problem is that there is no animation because just the first frame is rendered.

Here's my main C++ source code :

```
#include "qtapplication.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtApplication w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My qtapplication.h file :

```
include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qtapplication.h"
#include "HSGLWidget.hpp"

class QtApplication : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtApplication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QtApplication();

private:
    Ui::QtApplicationClass ui;
    HSGLWidget *_glwidget;
};
```

My qtapplication.cpp file :

```
#include "qtapplication.h"

QtApplication::QtApplication(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    this->_glwidget = NULL;

    if (this->_glwidget == NULL)
        this->_glwidget = new HSGLWidget();
    this->_glwidget->setVisible(true);
    setCentralWidget(this->_glwidget);
}

QtApplication::~QtApplication()
{

}
```

My HSGLWidjet.h file:

```
#include <QGLWidget>

class HSGLWidget : public QGLWidget {

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit HSGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        virtual ~HSGLWidget();

    protected:
        virtual void initializeGL();
        virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height);
        virtual void paintGL();

        virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent);

    private:
        void _onSetup();

    private:
        QTimer  *_timer;
};
```

And my HSGLWidjet.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HSGLWidget.hpp"

float toto_angle = 0.0f;

HSGLWidget::HSGLWidget(QWidget *parent) 
    :  QGLWidget(parent)
{
    this->_onSetup();
}

HSGLWidget::~HSGLWidget(void)
{

}

void HSGLWidget::initializeGL()
{   
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.20f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void HSGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    if (height == 0)
        height = 1;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void HSGLWidget::paintGL(void)
{
    std::cout << "PAINTGL" << std::endl;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glEnable(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(toto_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    toto_angle+=1.0f;
    glPopMatrix();
}

void HSGLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent)
{

}

void HSGLWidget::_onSetup()
{

}
```

The string 'PAINTGL' is written just for the first frame. Normally, paintGL is called automatically. I'm really lost in front of this situation. Does anyone can help me, please ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no problem at all**, that's the standard behavior.

You see, `paint()` and `paintGL()` are called only when the window needs to be draw. That is: when your application is created, when the window is resized, or moved around. Only then `paintGL()` is triggered. That's it!

If you want it to be called more than once, you will need to add a **timer** to execute `update()`, which is a method that forces the window to be redraw, which in turn triggers `paintGL()`. **Do not call `paintGL()` directly!**

[QTimer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) can help you achieve what you are looking for!

Comment: Can you please give a look to my question : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391673/getting-error-using-svm-with-surf)