# Getting error using SVM with SURF

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

Below is my code , which is running fine but after a long processing it show me the run time error

```
// Initialize constant values
const int nb_cars = files.size();
const int not_cars = files_no.size();
const int num_img = nb_cars + not_cars; // Get the number of images
// Initialize your training set.
cv::Mat training_mat(num_img,dictionarySize,CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat labels(0,1,CV_32FC1);

std::vector<string> all_names;

all_names.assign(files.begin(),files.end());
all_names.insert(all_names.end(), files_no.begin(), files_no.end());

// Load image and add them to the training set
int count = 0;
vector<string>::const_iterator i;
string Dir;
for (i = all_names.begin(); i != all_names.end(); ++i)
{
    Dir=( (count < files.size() ) ? YourImagesDirectory : YourImagesDirectory_2);

    Mat row_img = cv::imread( Dir +*i, 0 );

    detector.detect( row_img, keypoints);

    RetainBestKeypoints(keypoints, 20); // retain top 10 key points

    extractor->compute( row_img, keypoints, descriptors_1);

    //uncluster.push_back(descriptors_1);
    descriptors.reshape(1,1);

    bow.add(descriptors_1);

    ++count;
}

int count_2=0;
vector<string>::const_iterator k;
Mat vocabulary = bow.cluster();
dextract.setVocabulary(vocabulary);


for (k = all_names.begin(); k != all_names.end(); ++k)
{
    Dir=( (count_2 < files.size() ) ? YourImagesDirectory : YourImagesDirectory_2);

    row_img = cv::imread( Dir +*k, 0 );

    detector.detect( row_img, keypoints);

    RetainBestKeypoints(keypoints, 20);

    dextract.compute( row_img, keypoints, descriptors_1);

    descriptors_1.reshape(1,1);

    training_mat.push_back(descriptors_1);

    labels.at< float >(count_2, 0) = (count_2<nb_cars)?1:-1;

    ++count_2;
}
```

Error :

```
OpenCv Error : Formats of input argument do not match() in unknown function , file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 652
```

[image]

I made the `descriptor_1` in second loop to reshape into row for SVM , but error is not solving

Comment: What about using :
`Mat labelsMat(num_img, CV_32FC1, labels);`
`Mat training_mat(num_img,CV_32FC1, trainingData);`

Comment: @Flying You want to say that my arguments are not organized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i find out after 3 days that my error is in labeling , when i label the image i got the  error there , and yes above answer is also relevant that using less number of images also cause the error , but in my case this is not the reason , When i start checking error line by line , the error starts from here :

```
labels.at< float >(count_2, 0) = (count_2<nb_cars)?1:-1;
```

Because of the line :

```
Mat labels(0,1,CV_32FC1);
```

Instead of :

```
Mat labels(num_img,1,CV_32FC1);
```

and i should use

```
my_img.convertTo( training_mat.row(count_2), CV_32FC1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to cluster with less features then the number of classes.

You can take more images or more then 10 descriptors from each image.

Comment: +1 ,This may be one of the cause of error , but looking at the error `start after step 6` mean the major error is in final/last loop

Comment: @GilLevi When i check it line by line , i got the error here : `training_mat.push_back(descriptors_1);`